# Using AVA with jsdom, load and execute remote scripts

Tags: jsdom, ava

I'm writing a test with AVA and jsdom.

This works:

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native')
const jsdom = require('jsdom')
const {JSDOM} = jsdom
const url = 'http://localhost:8000'

rp(url).then((body) => {
  const options = {
    url: url,
    resources: 'usable',
    runScripts: 'dangerously',
  }

  let dom = new JSDOM(body, options)

  dom.window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      console.log(dom.serialize()) // works, prints <html><head></head><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>
    })
  })
})
```

An external script adds an h1 to the document body.

```
// external.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.write('<h1>Hello world!</h1>')
})
```

This is the markup at http://localhost:8000:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JSDOM test</title>
    <script src="external.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try the same thing in a test:

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native')
const test = require('ava')
const jsdom = require('jsdom')
const {JSDOM} = jsdom
const url = 'http://localhost:8000'

test('Check custom CSS', t => {
  return rp(url).then((body) => {
    const options = {
      url: url,
      resources: 'usable',
      runScripts: 'dangerously',
    }

    let dom = new JSDOM(body, options)

    dom.window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      setImmediate(() => {
        console.log(dom.serialize()) // nothing gets printed
      })
    })

    t.pass('passed')
  })
})
```

`console.log` isn't called. I would expect `<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>` to get printed, rather than there being no output.

In summary, I want to:

- Grab the response body from a url
- Create a new jsdom object from it
- Execute the scripts linked to in the response body's head tags
- Let the scripts change the markup
- Print the resulting modified markup

What is the best way of going about doing this?

Here's a minimum working example: https://github.com/cg433n/jsdom-test